# What would cause the C/C++ <, <=, and == operators to return true if either argument is NaN?

Tags: c++, c, nan, ieee-754

My understanding of the rules of IEEE-754 floating-point comparisons is that all comparison operators except `!=` will return false if either or both arguments are NaN, while the `!=` operator will return true. I can easily reproduce this behavior with a simple standalone test:

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < 4; ++ii)
{
    float a = (ii & 1) != 0 ? NAN : 1.0f;
    float b = (ii & 2) != 0 ? NAN : 2.0f;
    #define TEST(OP) printf("%4.1f %2s %4.1f => %s\n", a, #OP, b, a OP b ? "true" : "false");
    TEST(<)
    TEST(>)
    TEST(<=)
    TEST(>=)
    TEST(==)
    TEST(!=)
}
```

This prints the expected results: (NaN is formatted as `-1.$` in the MSVC runtime)

```
 1.0  <  2.0 => true
 1.0  >  2.0 => false
 1.0 <=  2.0 => true
 1.0 >=  2.0 => false
 1.0 ==  2.0 => false
 1.0 !=  2.0 => true
-1.$  <  2.0 => false
-1.$  >  2.0 => false
-1.$ <=  2.0 => false
-1.$ >=  2.0 => false
-1.$ ==  2.0 => false
-1.$ !=  2.0 => true
 1.0  < -1.$ => false
 1.0  > -1.$ => false
 1.0 <= -1.$ => false
 1.0 >= -1.$ => false
 1.0 == -1.$ => false
 1.0 != -1.$ => true
-1.$  < -1.$ => false
-1.$  > -1.$ => false
-1.$ <= -1.$ => false
-1.$ >= -1.$ => false
-1.$ == -1.$ => false
-1.$ != -1.$ => true
```

However, when I paste this chunk of code down in the depths of my application's inner-loops, where all the floating-point computations are performed, I get these inexplicable results:

```
 1.0  <  2.0 => true
 1.0  >  2.0 => false
 1.0 <=  2.0 => true
 1.0 >=  2.0 => false
 1.0 ==  2.0 => false
 1.0 !=  2.0 => true
-1.$  <  2.0 => true
-1.$  >  2.0 => false
-1.$ <=  2.0 => true
-1.$ >=  2.0 => false
-1.$ ==  2.0 => true
-1.$ !=  2.0 => false
 1.0  < -1.$ => true
 1.0  > -1.$ => false
 1.0 <= -1.$ => true
 1.0 >= -1.$ => false
 1.0 == -1.$ => true
 1.0 != -1.$ => false
-1.$  < -1.$ => true
-1.$  > -1.$ => false
-1.$ <= -1.$ => true
-1.$ >= -1.$ => false
-1.$ == -1.$ => true
-1.$ != -1.$ => false
```

For some reason, the `<`, `<=`, and `==` operators are unexpectedly returning true when either or both arguments are NaN. Furthermore, the `!=` operator is unexpectedly returning false.

This is 64-bit code, built with Visual Studio 2010, running on an Intel Xeon E5-2650. Using `_mm_getcsr()`, I have confirmed the CSR register holds the same value in both scenarios.

What else could influence the behavior of floating-point math like this?

Comment: I hate to have only a Dilbert quote to offer, but “here's a nickel, kid. Get yourself a better compiler”

Comment: You sure their legacy quasi-C89 mode is advertized as IEEE-754 conforming? Anyway, do you have fast-math or some such enabled?

Comment: Seems like your compiler is throwing some parts of the specification for performance...

Comment: Should probably drop the “C” tag, as VS doesn’t actually support C.

Comment: I think on some platforms there is a pragma or privileged instruction or some such that flips the FP processor and/or C code generation into a "lax" mode where strange things can happen.

Comment: Seems like the compiler assumed it could save one compare instruction by assuming that a < b is the opposite of a >= b. Never mind that it produces nonsense results in this case.

Comment: Snarkiness about your choice of compiler aside, this behavior is actually pretty fascinating.  Any chance you can post disassembly of what VS is generating for the second case?

Comment: @gnasher729: that’s an excellent hypothesis.  I suspect that sean’s application’s inner loops are compiled under the VS equivalent of -ffinite-math, which would allow this behavior.

Comment: BTW, your testcase printout would be much easier to follow if it printed the iteration number and/or the NaNness of the two variables for each step.

Comment: A good test would be to reorder your test cases and see if that impacts which ones fail. If it is the compiler "out-thinking you", then the first one to run would succeed and the remainder may fail.

Comment: I do believe @gnasher729 is correct. The < and > cases each use an identical COMISS instruction, followed by JAE and JBE, respectively. If I then change the compiler to use /fp:strict instead of /fp:fast then it behaves correctly. Only the == and != comparisons became slower, with an additional JP instruction to handle the NaNs.

Comment: When you say "down in the depths of my application's inner loops", does that happen to be a different project?

Comment: @Lilshieste: yes, with different compiler settings, apparently.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This behavior is due to the [`/fp:fast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx) MSVC compiler option, which (among other things) permits the compiler to perform comparisons without regard to proper NaN behavior in an effort to generate faster code. Using [`/fp:precise`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx) or [`/fp:strict`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx) instead causes these comparisons to behave as expected when presented with NaN arguments.

Comment: +1 and added links. Keep in mind you can set this behavior for specific code sections with `#pragma float_control` too.

Comment: Strangely, the `/fp:fast` option only triggers this invalid NaN behavior in the context of a larger application. When I apply `/fp:fast` to this code in a standalone `main()` function, it behaved correctly.

Comment: Thank you @BillyONeal, that's exactly what I needed. Very little code needs strict NaN handling.